# Use xpath to get maximum value within tables

Tags: python, html, xpath, max

I have a large html menu file in a general file format and I need to get the max price for each menu item.  This is an example of a piece of the menu file:

```
### File Name: "menu" (All types ".") ###
</div>
     <div class="menu-item-prices">
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                10
            </td>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                14
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>

</div>
     <div class="menu-item-prices">
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                100
            </td>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                1
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

I need my program to return a list of the maximum price within each menu item, i.e, maxprices=['14','100'] for this example.  I have tried the following code in Python:

```
#!/user/bin/python

from lxml import html
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
from lxml.etree import XPath

def main():
    """ Drive function """
    fpath = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'menu')
    hfile = open(fpath)  # open html file
    tree = html.fromstring(hfile.read())

    prices_path = XPath('//*[@class="menu-item-prices"]/table/tr')  
    maxprices = []

    for p in prices_path(tree):
        prices = p.xpath('//td/text()')
        prices = [el.strip() for el in prices]
        maxprice = max(prices)
        maxprices.append(maxprice)
        print maxprices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I  have also tried

```
prices = tree.xpath('//*[@class="menu-item-prices"]'
                    '//tr[not(../tr/td > td)]/text()')
prices = [el.strip() for el in prices]
```

instead of the above looping strategy. Neither returns the necessary max prices for each category. How can I modify my code to correctly get these prices?  Thank you.

Comment: What is the output that you get? Or does this error out?

Comment: @Obsidian - the code above outputs ['14', '14'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least 1 problem - you are *comparing strings* but need to convert the prices to `float` and then get the maximum per each table row.

Complete example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """
<div>
     <div class="menu-item-prices">
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                    10
                </td>
                <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                    14
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item-prices">
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                100
            </td>
            <td class="menu-item-price-amount">
                1
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
"""

tree = fromstring(data)
for item in tree.xpath("//div[@class='menu-item-prices']/table/tr"):
    prices = [float(price.strip()) for price in item.xpath(".//td[@class='menu-item-price-amount']/text()")]
    print(max(prices))
```

Prints:

```
14.0
100.0
```